# Capturing POST Parameters Inside UIWebView for an iOS App

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest, uiwebviewdelegate, hybrid-mobile-app

I am displaying a simple `HTML` page inside the `UIWebView`. The page contains the login and password text box. When I click the login button I pass that information (username and password) using post to some URL.

I have breakpoints inside the `UIWebView` `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method but I only see the original login page URL and not the one that it posted. When I use Charles (Network debugging) tool it shows that the `POST` parameters were passed to the correct `URL` but that request was never captured inside the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method.

How can I access the parameters inside the `UIWebView` so I can perform some other action?

Comment: Hey, did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate method, you can capture the POST body of the request. See code below:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"BODY: %@",[[[NSString alloc]initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);

}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you